# Rails form_tag is using GET instead of PUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, put

I'm using a `form_tag` to update an attribute in my 'Car' model. Everything should work except when I check the logs its using GET instead of the PUT like it should.

## routes

```
apply_superadmin_apply_coupons_path -   PUT /superadmin/apply_coupons/apply(.:format) superadmin/apply_coupons#apply
superadmin_apply_coupons_path -         GET /superadmin/apply_coupons(.:format) superadmin/apply_coupons#index
```

## view

```
<form class="super-admin-apply-coupons form-horizontal">

  <%= form_tag(apply_superadmin_apply_coupons_path, action: 'apply', method: 'PUT') do %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2"> Select car</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 apply-coupon-wrap">
        <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@cars, "id", "device_number"), class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2">Select coupon code</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4 apply-coupon-wrap">
        <%= select_tag :coupon_code_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@coupon_codes, "id", "name"), class:"form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
        <%= submit_tag 'Apply', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

Its obviously just redirecting back to the index page at the moment without triggering the apply action I'm wanting it to.

Comment: Try rmoving `<form>` tags from .html.erb

Comment: @RAJ, thanks that did it

Comment: This question doesnt make sense, your code is buggy.

Comment: Why are you using the `action` option? That's inferred by Rails from the path. It also looks like this is a resource, why aren't you using `form_for @resource` instead of `form_tag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably producing two `<form>` tag in your view, one is the html form tag, the other is from `<%=form_tag(...)%>`. Just try to remove the html form tag might make it.